# C macro define many variables in one go

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

I need to define many variables and I don't want to do it one by one. Plus, I want to learn more about macros. So let's say I have to define x1, x2, x3, x4, x5 like this:

```
int x1;
int x2;
int x3;
int x4;
int x5;
```

Can I do it with a macro? like this:

```
#define defint(i) int x(i)//x(i) does not work. I need to somehow combine x and i. How??
```

and then make a for loop for how many variables I want to define?

***UPDATE***: I'll use it to define many handlers for many traps in some code for an `Operating system` and hence I don't want to use array (I want my bootloader to be as small as possible :P)

***UPDATE2***: seems I have to make myself more clear. Since it's os code, so it also has assembly code. so half code is in **C** and half in asm. I define all variables via macro in assembly and use them in **C** declaring them `extern` :).

Comment: C has arrays for exactly this purpose. `int x[5];`

Comment: You cannot mix compile time stuff (the preprocessor `#define`s) and run-time stuff (the compiler proper `for`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use token pasting:

```
#define DEFINT(i) int x ## i
```

Also, see how I did *not* include the trailing semi-colon, since you want that when the macro is used, to make it look like a statement.